# Android studio asking for android sdk path

Tags: android, android-studio

So i just downloaded android studio and sdk tools (not the bundle) and when i installed and run android studio it asks for sdk path.i know where it is but its a zip file i"ve tried to give it the location both extracted and un extracted but won't work.

Comment: can you post the complete error.

Comment: Make sure the location is correct

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try setting the path in your Project's local.properties like this:

```
sdk.dir=/path/to/sdk/folder
```

You need to use the absolute path of your unzipped/extracted SDK folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting ANDROID_HOME variable in your environment variables to the value of your extracted sdk location

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio > File > Sdk Location > Android SDK location: select the path where you have android sdk(extracted folder) > Press ok

Now you can see the android studio added sdk path

Answer (score 0):

close the Android Studio and reopen to complete the installation guide.

Solution found: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6h1WGKJKxXI